# Save SQL result in php function as array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

so I am basically trying to take the quote_author and quote_text results from SQL through a php function and then display it in stylized html. When I call the function I want to get 2 variables $quote_text and $quote_author, so I can put them in two separe divs in html, because they are stylized differently.

This is my code

```
function get_quotes(){

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");
$sql = "SELECT quote_text, quote_author FROM quotes ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       //how can I get the two results $row['quote_text'] and $row['quote_author'] 
       //out of the function
   }
}

get_quotes();
echo $row['quote_text'];
echo $row['quote_author'];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return ['text' => $row['quote_text'], 'author' => $row['quote_author']]`

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop if you limit the query to one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `return` statement to return the results from the function. You also don't need a `while` loop, since the query only returns one row.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc();
return $row;
```

Then the caller does:

```
$row = get_quotes();
if ($row) {
    echo $row['quote_text'];
    echo $row['quote_author'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
function get_quotes(){
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");
    $sql = "SELECT quote_text, quote_author FROM quotes ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}

$row = get_quotes();
echo $row['quote_text'];
echo $row['quote_author'];
```

Comment: won't you check if `$row` isn't null before accessing it's indices?

Comment: @ciriusrob Sure, but it wasn't a requirement. I'd also check for connection errors.